# QGIS Cross Tab of Towns and Routes

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

Using QGIS, I have a layer with 100 towns. I have another layer with 200 cycle routes, each with a different name. I want to create (automatically natch) a table that will help the people in each town, for example, get a list of all of the routes that pass within 1Km of their town centre.

Answer (score 1):

If you bring your layers into Spatialite, here's a one-liner to get what you want:

```
SELECT t.id, b.Trail_Name FROM towns AS t, bike_trails AS b
WHERE ST_Intersects(b.Geometry, BUFFER(t.Geometry, 1000));
```

This query will select each bike_trail name from the bike_trails layer which passes within 1000 m of a town, and list all the town ID's with each trail name.

Comment: +1 Nice solution! You might want to add some brief instructions on how to do an SQL query on a spatialite layer within QGIS. Would you use the Spatialite Manager plugin, for example?

Comment: Thanks. I'd probably use the DBManager plugin within QGIS. Other wise spatialite_gui.